# OpenID.net website is strangely behaving for 2 day now

Tags: website, archiving, openid

On firefox 3 on WinXP, Win7 and Ubuntu when I try to access www.OpenID.net it asks me to save a gzip archive. Is that normal ? I need to look at the documentation, is their an alternative sources ?